# Show information of subclass in list_display django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two classes in **models.py**:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
   field_one = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   field_two = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   field_three = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   [...] #other fields
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.field_one

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
   relation_model_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
   other_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   [...]
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.relation_model_one.field_one
```

And your administration in admin.py is this:

```
class ModelTwoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ModelTwo
    extra = 0

class ModelOneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three',)
    inlines = [ModelTwoInline]
```

**My question is:**
Can I display the fields of the ModelTwo in list_display of the ModelOne? (The same for list_filter and search_fields)

I need this because I have many subclasses related to the main class!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can display anything you want in `list_display` by writing an instance method with the `@property` decorator, which then returns whatever you need, and including it in `list_display`. I don't think that works for `list_filter` though.

So, let's return to your `ModelOne` class:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    [...]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field_one

    @property
    def model_two_other_field(self):
        return ', '.join([m2.other_field for m2 in self.modeltwo_set.all()])
```

Then, in your ModelOneAdmin:

```
class ModelOneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three', 'model_two_other_field')
    [...]
```

I would note, for the record, that when you do this, you'll be requiring a database hit for *every* ModelOne instance being displayed. So, if you're listing 50 instances, you're incurring the overhead of 50 separate queries (one for each call of `self.modeltwo_set.all()`). That doesn't necessarily mean you shouldn't do it -- it might be the right answer, depending on your situation. Just be aware that it could be quite an expensive operation.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the related name of the fields or `RelatedModel._meta.get_fields`

```
class ModelOneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three')
    inlines = [ModelTwoInline]

    def get_list_display(self, request):
        extra_fields = [
            f.name for model in self.inlines 
            for f in ModelTwo._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=False) 
        ]
        return self.list_display + extra_fields
```